# Delimit a watershed associated with a polygon - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, dem, watershed

I have nearly the same question as [Calculating watershed associated with polygon using DEM and QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/464057) but for ArcGIS Pro.

I am starting with a polygon representing property boundaries and I need to delimit the area (with a polygon) that drains water into that polygon. If possible, I want to automate the process with a workflow, so that I don't have to pick points manually and can repeat it quickly for new locations.

Comment: All the information you require, including videos to watch is [here](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=arcpro+hydrology+tools).